# Graphics problem in notification area of xfce panel

Tags: xfce, notification

I tried to install some themes from xfce looks. But after removing them I get some problems in notification area applets like blueman and network manager. I attached a screenshot. Please help me if you have a solution[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled xfce4-goodies and gtk3-engine-xfce.